# Azure Site Recovery Protected VMs Limit to 10

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-site-recovery

We are setting up Azure Site Recovery for a VmWare environment and we've been through the process of setting up the configuration server and the site recovery wizard, but we're a bit stuck at selecting the VMs to replicate. When we select more than 10 it comes with an error "You can select a maximum of 10 items to protect"?

We've built the server using the following specs which according to Microsoft should be enough to accommodate 100 servers.

Spec: 8vCPU, 16GB Memory

Is there a limitation I have missed?

The links I have followed are:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-plan-capacity-vmware

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/vmware-physical-large-deployment

Answer (score 0):

You can have maximum of 100 server / CS  but at a time you can't select more then 10 . Currently, you can protect all of your Azure VMs with Azure Site Recovery, the only limitation is that you can enable replication in batches of 10 VMs at the time This is in order to maintain replication bandwidth and minimize the impact of the cache storage and target store accounts utilization during the initial replication process. Ex: You have 15 Azure virtual machines. You could protect all of them in 2 batches. First batch of 10 VMs (simultaneously) and then a second batch for the remaining 5 VMs.

More info:
IP address retention for Azure virtual machine failover: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-retain-ip-azure-vm-failover

Azure to Azure replication architecture: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-architecture

About networking in Azure to Azure replication: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-about-networking

Create and customize recovery plans: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-create-recovery-plans

Set up disaster recovery for Azure VMs to a secondary Azure region: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-tutorial-enable-replication

Run a disaster recovery drill for Azure VMs to a secondary Azure region: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-tutorial-dr-drill

Fail over and fail back Azure VMs between Azure regions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-tutorial-failover-failback

Kindly let us know if the above helps or you need further assistance on this issue.